# How to style the element which loads after computation of result in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple addition program using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

HTML code is as follows:

```
<head>
<title>Input Output</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="io.css">
<body>
<h1>Sum App</h1>
<div class="container">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="io.js"></script>
    First Number <input type="text" id="numOne">
    Second Number <input type="text" id="numTwo">
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="submitBut()">Submit</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <div class="screen" id="screen1"></div>
</div >
```

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
function submitBut(){
    var numOne= document.getElementById("numOne").value;
    var numTwo= document.getElementById("numTwo").value;
    var sum=parseInt(numOne)+parseInt(numTwo);
    var element= document.createElement("p");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

I want to now style the result which as per the code seats in between paragraph tags with id "result". 
What are the ways using which this is possible?

I tried using a standard style sheet format as below:

```
#result {
    font-size: 45-px;
    background-color= Yellow;
}
```

However, it is not working at all. Kindly let me know possible fixes.

Regards,

Comment: Your CSS looks invalid, try `#result {
font-size: 45px;
background-color: yellow;
}`

Comment: Also, your `element` is unused.

Comment: Check your CSS Path, Sometime it's not working at all, just Check by Applying background to whole page `*{ background-color:red;}` and `45-px;` is Wrong Syntax it's `45px;`

Comment: @PRABHATSINGHRAJPUT thanks! The -px was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the CSS you have written for this code. **It's Invalid.**
Change it like the following and it will work fine:

```
#result {
    font-size: 45px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```